# Add multiple elements to the text file in a specific way using Bash

Tags: bash

I have a text file that contains a list of "word sequences" and I need to add some "" and "," to each word sequence, I´m thinking in use a bash command.
Here is the data:

```
NTSS
NGTG
NVSQ
NITL
NFTS
...
```

I need to add "" to each word sequence and separate with ","
Here an expected output:

```
"NTSS",
"NGTG",
"NVSQ",
"NITL",
...
```

Any recommendation with BASH to do that?

Comment: Should the very last sequence get a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in many ways, but `sed` is perfect for the job.

```
sed 's/^.*$/"\0",/' < file.txt
```

This replacement simply matches the whole line and replaces it according to what you need.

The one above is a regular expression replacement, which has the structure:

```
s/<pattern to match>/<replacement>/
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `.*` matches any character any number of times
- `$` matches the end of the line
- In the replacement part, `\0` represents the whole string that has matched the pattern (the entire line in this case)

Check out some regular expression tutorial for more.

If you prefer a purely bash alternative, you can use:

```
while read -r line; do echo "\"${line}\","; done < file.txt
```

Comment: To read each line verbatim, use `while IFS= read -r line`. If you want to strip leading/trailing whitespace, then `while read -r line`. You almost always want to use `-r` with read.

Comment: True, answer fixed.